# Get the count of duplicate keys in a hash

Tags: ruby

I have a hash say

```
test = [ {:a1=>"a", :b1=>"q"},
         {:a1=>"c", :b1=>"z"},
         {:a1=>"a", :b1=>"zcq"} ]
```

Need to find out count of key with `"a"` (e.g. `:a1=>"a"`) in a hash. The output should be 2 if i am searching for key as `"a"`.
How to find the count of the selected key.

Comment: A hash can't have duplicate keys. You have an array of hashes, which is different. It also sounds like you're confusing keys and values because all your tests for `"a"` are looking for that particular value.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
test.count { |item| item[:a1] == 'a' }
```